# Dynamic memory allocation in arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

I have spent last few hours trying to debug my code but I failed to do so. I think the problem lies in me not fully understanding dynamic memory allocation, however I could've made some other mistakes aswell. The question here is a bit more of a personal problem and I'm sorry if someone finds this question not fulfilling "Make it relevant to others".

I've been given the next assigment:

Create an array `A[]` out of `n` random elements from interval 0-100. Create a function which splits two arrays such as: array `B[]` contains elements `> 50` while `C[]` contains rest of the elements. Create arrays A and B using dynamic memory allocation. Arguments of the function have to be all three arrays and their respective lengths.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Array(int *A, int *nA, int *B, int *nB, int *C, int*nC){

    int i;
    int nB1 = 0;
    int nC1 = 0;
    int *tmpB;
    int *tmpC;
    B = malloc((nB1+1)*sizeof(int));
    C = malloc((nC1+1)*sizeof(int));

    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0 ; i < nA ; i++){
        if(A[i] <= 50){
            C[i] = A[i];
            nC1++;
//    The idea here is to have a new array with basically
//    no length so that each time one element passes to either
//    B or A array that array gets increased at the same 
//    time as nC or nB 
            tmpC = realloc(C, sizeof(int) * nC1);
                if(tmpC == NULL){ 
                    printf("ERROR: realloc failed.\n");
                }
            C = tmpC;
//            C = realloc(C, nC1 + 1);
        }
        else{
            B[i] = A[i];
            nB1++;
            tmpB = realloc(B, sizeof(int) * nB1);
                if(tmpB == NULL){
                    printf("ERROR: realloc failed.\n");
                }
            B = tmpB;
//            B = realloc(B, nB1 + 1);

        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Array B: ");
    nB = nB1;
    for(i = 0 ; i < nB ; i++){
        printf("%d ", B[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Number of elements in array B: %d\n", nB);

    printf("\n");
    printf("Array C: ");
    nC = nC1;
    for(i = 0 ; i < nC ; i++){
        printf("%d ", C[i]);
    }    
    printf("\n");
    printf("Number of elements in array C: %d\n", nC);

}

void main(){

    int *A;
    int *B;
    int *C;
    int nA, nB, nC, i, r, j;
    nB = 0;
    nC = 0;

    printf("Enter the length of array A: ");
    scanf("%d", &nA);
    printf("\n");

    A = malloc(nA * sizeof(int));
    if (A == NULL){
        printf("ERROR: malloc failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));

    printf("Array A: ");

    for(i = 0 ; i < nA ; i++){
        r = rand() % 101;
        A[i] = r;
        printf("%d ", r);
    }
    printf("\n");
    Array(A, nA, B, nB, C, nC);
}
```

So far my code is breaking when:

User input from `nA` is higher than 6.
Code is working fine while array `A` has all elements which can be put in one single array such as `B` or `C`. But if elements can be split, last element of the array `A` is not shown properly on the screen while being in `B` or `C` array.

EDIT: Updated code so it's easier to keep track of my mistakes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void Array(int *A, int nA, int *B, int nB, int *C, int nC){

    int i;
    int nB1 = 0;
    int nC1 = 0;
    int *tmpB;
    int *tmpC;
     B = malloc(1*sizeof(int));
        if(B == NULL){ 
            printf("ERROR: malloc B failed.\n");
            return 1;
        }

    C = malloc(1*sizeof(int));    
        if(C == NULL){ 
            printf("ERROR: malloc  C failed.\n");
            return 1;
        }

    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0 ; i < nA ; i++){
        if(A[i] <= 50){
//            C[nC1] = A[i];
//            nC1++;
//                if( nC1 > 1){
//                    tmpC = realloc(C, sizeof(int) * nC1);
//                        if(tmpC == NULL){ 
//                            printf("ERROR: realloc C failed.\n");
//                            return 1;
//                        }
//                    C = tmpC;
//                }
            tmpC = realloc(C, sizeof(int) * nC1);
                if(tmpC == NULL){ 
                    printf("ERROR: realloc C failed.\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            C = tmpC;

            C[nC1++] = A[i];
    //                nC1++;
        }
        else{
//            B[nB1] = A[i];
//            nB1++;
//                if(nB1 > 1){
//                    tmpB = realloc(B, sizeof(int) * nB1);
//                        if(tmpB == NULL){
//                            printf("ERROR: realloc B failed.\n");
//                            return 1;
//                        }
//                    B = tmpB;
//                }
            tmpB = realloc(B, sizeof(int) * nB1);
                if(tmpB == NULL){
                    printf("ERROR: realloc B failed.\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            B = tmpB;  
            B[nB1++] = A[i];
//                    nB1++;
        }


    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Array B: ");
    nB = nB1;
    for(i = 0 ; i < nB ; i++){
        printf("%d ", B[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Number of elements in array B: %d\n", nB);

    printf("\n");
    printf("Array C: ");
    nC = nC1;
    for(i = 0 ; i < nC ; i++){
        printf("%d ", C[i]);
    }    
    printf("\n");
    printf("Number of elements in array C: %d\n", nC);
}

int main(){

    int *A;
    int *B;
    int *C;
    int nA, nB, nC, i, r;

    printf("Enter the length of array A: ");
    scanf("%d", &nA);
    printf("\n");

    A = malloc(nA * sizeof(int));
    if (A == NULL){
        printf("ERROR: malloc A failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));

    printf("Array A: ");

    for(i = 0 ; i < nA ; i++){
        r = rand() % 101;
        A[i] = r;
        printf("%d ", r);
    }
    printf("\n");
    Array(A, nA, B, nB, C, nC);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As I have understood the three arrays should be already created before the function call.

Comment: I made it this way since we might have an issue of wasting memory if all elements go only into one array, I think at least.

Comment: What are you trying to do with passing in `B` and `C` into the function `Array`. You overwrite the addresses once you pass them in. In other words, it like you didn't have to pass them in to begin with.

Comment: check the return of your malloc statements before using the pointer they return.  `[m][c][re]alloc` return a null if allocation fails.

Comment: I'm just trying to technically fulfill the assignment and using help from other vars inside the function `Array` to get the task done. I'd be more than happy to change it if I did that wrong or if there's a better way, I'm very open for criticism.

Comment: Why are you passing uninitialized values `B` and `C` to the `Array` function?

Comment: I'm using `return 1;` after each and nothing. I have a working code with two functions for `ArrayB` and `ArrayC` with predefined malloc for their arrays and no problems. @ryyker

Comment: I see that.  I was referring to those two calls at the beginning of your code example: `B = malloc((nB1+1)*sizeof(int));` and 
    `C = malloc((nC1+1)*sizeof(int));`  Although this is likely not your problem, it simplifies debug when you dont have to worry about null pointers :)

Comment: Check above you. @n.m.

Comment: Again nothing, I'm not sure if my logic for initializing those arrays and their 'malloc' is even supposed to work. @ryyker

Comment: @brajevicm What ryyker is getting at is `void Array(int *A, int *nA, int *B, int *nB, int *C, int*nC)` might as well be `void Array(int *A, int nA)` The function need no other information besides the location of the array and the size of the array. All those other variables should just be defined in the function.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that but as I said I was just trying to meet the requirements of the task, as my assistant told me that I should have those parameters in my function but I guess she had a different idea on how to solve this problem.

Comment: This does not really technically fulfil the assignment. The arguments to a function are two uninitialized pointers. They are required to be arrays. An uninitialized pointer is not an array.. Your function is also required to split the array, not to print anything. The caller may print the results to demonstrate that the function works.

Comment: You may also find this answer from earlier tonight helpful on the allocation/reallocation [**Spilt a string of integers based on delimiter and convert to int type?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36299842/spilt-a-string-of-integers-based-on-delimiter-and-convert-to-int-type)

Comment: Were you able to finish this?

Comment: Yes, however after few days so I thought there's no reason to bother you guys again.

Answer (score 0):

Logic error `B[i] = A[i];` in your condition should be `B[nB1] = A[i];`. Same thing with `C` array, should be  `C[nC1] = A[i]` (both of this in the loop).

Also, from KillaBytes bytes analysis. Yes, you should definitely realloc BEFORE adding the new value. Probably is the reason your program crashes eventually:

```
        else {
            nB1++; // since you started at size 0
            tmpB = realloc(B, sizeof(int) * nB1); //realloc to 0 = (sizeof(int) * 0) is bad
            if(tmpB == NULL){
                printf("ERROR: realloc failed.\n");
            }
            B = tmpB;
            B[nB1 - 1] = A[i];///*****KEY POINT, This happens at the very end***
        }
```

Still, there are many other problems, but not with the core logic. Especially with the the understanding of pointers. I'll try to list a few you need to think about:

- Nothing comes out of the `Array` function (besides the printed output), the original `B` and `C` remain the same.
- `A`, `B` (in the function), `C` (in the function) is not freed at the end. The idea is, for every malloc/calloc (realloc would free when successful), you would have to call free on the pointer to avoid any memory leakage *:) just a trivial point, but very good habit.*
- Error conditions shouldn't continue logic, simplest solution would be to kill the program

```
                if(tmpC == NULL){ 
                    printf("ERROR: realloc failed.\n");
                }
```

should be

```
                if(tmpC == NULL){ 
                    free(C);//unnecessary because the program is going to exit
                            // I would argue to get used to this, to force the habit
                            // to alway free all mallocs
                    printf("ERROR: realloc failed.\n");
                    exit(-1);// -1 is a generic value, error code that is checked
                             // if the caller cares to look (you can make it any int)
                }
```

- Now, if you wanted to "return" the value outside of for `B` and `C` `Array()` there are a few approaches, I'll demo one way.

```
void Array(int *A, int nA, int **B, int *nB, int **C, int *nC){ // funciton signature
```

Any time you use `B`, `nB`, `C`, `nC` in this function, use `*B`, `*nB`, `*C`, `*nC`. Eg:

```
    *B = malloc((*nB1+1)*sizeof(int));
    *C = malloc((*nC1+1)*sizeof(int));
```

And the call to the function from `main` should be:

```
printf("\n");
Array(A, nA, &B, &nB, &C, &nC);
```

Comment: I adjusted my code to people's advice however I still get that random high number from arrays `B` and `C`. Also sometimes program crashes on random input, for example I ran program twice with my input `nA` being 100 and it worked time but 3rd time it crashed.

Comment: Can you define crashed, like segmentation fault? Also might be useful to know what you are using to run the program (if you doing it from command line, or an IDE).

Comment: @brajevicm Updated, i think Killa has a point that I didn't see.

Comment: By using debugged from VS2015 I receive this `Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCA315E6DC (ntdll.dll) in CS323-V05.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x00007FFCA31B22B0)` . I'm using CodeLite and all I get is Program has stopped working thingy.

Comment: Yes, so it sounds equivalent to a segfault in a Linux environment. Means you're dereferencing a bad pointer. From my understanding, `realloc` tries to give back the same pointer so for an increment of 4 bytes (sizeof int), it'll probably work most the time. But if a new pointer is given, you're not assigning it to `B`, and the using the new `B` to insert the value, the old B is probably been freed. The update I made from Killa's response should fix that.

Comment: Now I'm getting `ERROR: realloc B failed.` or `ERROR: realloc C failed.` I will make an EDIT with my current code on the main post.

Comment: @brajevicm I didn't really check the logic behind the `nB1` to thoroughly, lemme edit. Updated.

Comment: I'm getting this error all over the place when I add `*` in the fucntion to `B`, `nB`, `C` and `nC` : `error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')`

Comment: @brajevicm First, did you get it working with the first code block? You should be able to get that working without the manipulation of pointers (the second half of my answer). In the second part, please note `void Array(int *A, int *nA, int *B, int *nB, int *C, int*nC)` changed to `void Array(int *A, int nA, int **B, int *nB, int **C, int *nC)`

Comment: It was working fine up to the pointer where I started changing my function prototype, I will recheck it again in ~2 hours once I get home @SGM1

Comment: @brajevicm I highly recommend sitting down with someone who understands pointer, like your TA, and walk through what's happening. Start from you working code.

Comment: @brajevicm If you still have issue, please update the question with your current state.

Comment: I will probably leave this code as it is now for the next day or two while I read and watch some tutorials on pointers. I feel like I understand the theory behind pointers but when I have mulptile vars I just get lost.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to take a crack at this I guess. I found some notable issues with your code that would be resolved with some structural changes towards your implementation. Some of the lesser ones:

```
void main() {

// Code above here left out.
A = malloc(nA * sizeof(int));
if (A == NULL){
    printf("ERROR: malloc failed.\n");
    return 1; // Might be a problem here.
}
```

You return an integer in main when there is not enough memory to allocate for `A`. This could cause issues on some compilers - or if you hate warnings in general a simple fix from `void main` to `int main` will clear this up.

2nd, in your function `Array` you have

```
void Array(int *A, int *nA, int *B, int *nB, int *C, int *nC)
```

however, you begin to use `nA nB` and `nC` as just `int` instead of `int *` which is a mismatch of types. You could change to

```
void Array(int *A, int nA, int *B, int nB, int *C, int nC)
```

Lastly and most importantly, you run into heap errors by using uninitialized `ints` to create memory for the arrays passed in:

```
int nB1;
int nC1;

B = malloc((nB1 + 1)*sizeof(int));
C = malloc((nC1 + 1)*sizeof(int));
```

It would be better to instead add just one `int` to the arrays without using `nB1` and `nC1`.

```
B = malloc(1*sizeof(int));
C = malloc(1*sizeof(int));
```

You should first make checks as to whether `B` and `C` are empty arrays when they are passed in, then add memory to them as you see fit.

```
if (A[i] <= 50){
        C[i] = A[i];
        nC1++;
        //    The idea here is to have a new array with basically
        //    no length so that each time one element passes to either
        //    B or A array that array gets increased at the same 
        //    time as nC or nB 
        tmpC = realloc(C, sizeof(int) * nC1);
        if (tmpC == NULL){
            printf("ERROR: realloc failed.\n");
        }
        C = tmpC;
      }
```

`tmpC` is realloc'd but `C` is never given more space thus when assigning the value `C[i] = A[i]` it crashes. You need to expand on maintaining the arrays `C` and `B`.

**EDIT**

Disregard the comment about reallocation, the `realloc` operation you have is fine.

You iterate through each element in the array `A`, if the value is less than or equal to 50 you insert into array `C` otherwise `B`. However, you might have a few elements that satisfy the first condition but then the next condition could be satisfied. You then assign like so `B[i] = A[i]` but as stated you are at element 3 in `A` but you insert at element 1 in `B`, so using `i` to iterate for both is not correct. Follow *SGM1*'s advice for reading into each array using `nB1` and `nC1`, and also *ryyker* for the comment on reallocation.

I was able to compile and run this every time, however now you have to deal with actually assigning the values now:

```
for (i = 0; i < nA; i++){
    if (A[i] <= 50){
        C[nC1] = A[i];
        nC1++;
        tmpC = (int *)realloc(C, sizeof(int) * nC1);
        if (tmpC == NULL){
            printf("ERROR: realloc failed.\n");
        }
        C = tmpC;
        //            C = realloc(C, nC1 + 1);
    }
```

Comment: _tmpC is realloc'd but C is never given more space_.  Yes, I think it is..  The line: `C = tmpC;` is what does it.     It appears to me that `realloc()` is used precisely the way it is supposed to be used.  Your point about using uninitialized integers to create memory though is spot on.

Comment: I have changed what you have told me but I'm not sure what you meant by maintaining. Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @ryyker I think he meant order matters, AKA `C = tmpC;` (still after realloc) should happen before the `C[i] = A[i];` line

Comment: @brajevicm There is a heap corruption error given because there are multiple calls to `realloc` but you start ahead in each array `C[i]` then you immediately try and place the next value in from `A[i]` into `B[i]` which causes your program to crash because you did not put anything in `B[0]` or `B[1]`, etc. I've adjusted my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @KillaBytes "because you did not put anything in B[0] or B[1]" isn't accurate. The exception happen because at some point in the program, the user does not have access to the memory address for the `i`th element in `B` or `C` (which are allocated to numbers less than `i`).

Comment: @SGM1 Yes you are correct, thank you for clarifying 'memory access of the `i`th element'.

Answer (score -1):

There were a few bugs. There were a lot of errors/warnings flagged by the compiler (i.e. always compile with `-Wall`)

In the `Array` prototype, `nA` was defined as `*nA` [a pointer] but you used `nA` throughout the body.

`*nB` and `*nC` were correct, but near the bottom you needed:

```
*nB = nB1;
*nC = nC1;
```

There was a lot of replication code for all arrays. Each array had a custom loop to print it. To simplify, create a "print array" function.

The reallocation of `B` and `C` are similar, so, once again, create a common function.

Other bugs aside, while `Array` created `B` and `C`, it had no way to pass the *updated* values back to `main`. So, in the prototype, we need `int **Bp` and `int **Cp`.

In all, `Array` had two input values and four return values.

Here's the corrected code [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// prtarray -- print an array
void
prtarray(int *arr,int count,const char *sym)
{

    printf("\n");
    printf("Array %s:",sym);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf(" %d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Number of elements in array %s: %d\n",sym,count);
}

// growarray -- grow array
int *
growarray(int *arr,int *pcount,int val)
{
    int off;

    off = *pcount;
    arr = realloc(arr,sizeof(int) * (off + 1));
    arr[off] = val;

    *pcount = off + 1;

    return arr;
}

// BUGFIX: we need "int nA" and _not_ "int *nA"
#if 0
void
Array(int *A, int *nA, int *B, int *nB, int *C, int *nC)
#else
void
Array(int *A, int nA, int **Bp, int *nB, int **Cp, int *nC)
#endif
{
#if 1
    int *B = NULL;
    int *C = NULL;
#endif
    int i;

    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < nA; i++) {
        if (A[i] <= 50)
            C = growarray(C,nC,A[i]);
        else
            B = growarray(B,nB,A[i]);
    }

    *Bp = B;
    *Cp = C;
}

int
main()
{

    int *A;
    int *B;
    int *C;
    int nA;
    int nB;
    int nC;

    nB = 0;
    nC = 0;

    printf("Enter the length of array A: ");
    scanf("%d", &nA);
    printf("\n");

    A = malloc(nA * sizeof(int));
    if (A == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: malloc failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    time_t t;

    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    for (int i = 0; i < nA; i++)
        A[i] = rand() % 101;
    prtarray(A,nA,"A");

#if 0
    Array(A, nA, B, nB, C, nC);
#else
    Array(A, nA, &B, &nB, &C, &nC);
#endif

    prtarray(B,nB,"B");
    prtarray(C,nC,"C");

    return 0;
}
```

But, dynamic arrays "cry out" for using a `struct` to control things. The code becomes even simpler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// array control
struct array {
    int *arr_data;                      // data
    int arr_count;                      // array count
    const char *arr_sym;                // array name
};

// arrinit -- initialize array
void
arrinit(struct array *arr,const char *sym)
{

    arr->arr_data = NULL;
    arr->arr_count = 0;
    arr->arr_sym = sym;
}

// arrprint -- print an array
void
arrprint(struct array *arr)
{

    printf("\n");
    printf("Array %s:",arr->arr_sym);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr->arr_count; i++)
        printf(" %d ", arr->arr_data[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Number of elements in array %s: %d\n",arr->arr_sym,arr->arr_count);
}

// arrgrow -- grow array
void
arrgrow(struct array *arr,int val)
{
    int off;

    off = arr->arr_count;
    arr->arr_data = realloc(arr->arr_data,sizeof(int) * (off + 1));
    arr->arr_data[off] = val;

    arr->arr_count = off + 1;
}

// BUGFIX: we need "int nA" and _not_ "int *nA"
void
Array(struct array *A, struct array *B, struct array *C)
{
    int i;
    int val;

    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < A->arr_count; i++) {
        val = A->arr_data[i];
        if (val <= 50)
            arrgrow(C,val);
        else
            arrgrow(B,val);
    }
}

int
main()
{
    struct array A;
    struct array B;
    struct array C;
    int nA;

    arrinit(&A,"A");
    arrinit(&B,"B");
    arrinit(&C,"C");

    printf("Enter the length of array A: ");
    scanf("%d", &nA);
    printf("\n");

    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    for (int i = 0; i < nA; i++)
        arrgrow(&A,rand() % 101);

    arrprint(&A);

    Array(&A, &B, &C);

    arrprint(&B);
    arrprint(&C);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's a clean wrapper for `realloc` to use in the above.

```
// qrealloc -- reallocate with null check
void *
qrealloc(void *ptr,size_t len)
{

#if 1
    // what is normally sufficient
    ptr = realloc(ptr,len);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"qrealloc: realloc failure -- len=%lu\n",len);
        exit(1);
    }
#else
    // what valgrind needs
    void *tmp = realloc(ptr,len);
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        free(ptr);
        fprintf(stderr,"qrealloc: realloc failure -- ptr=%p len=%lu\n",ptr,len);
        exit(1);
    }
    ptr = tmp;
#endif

    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: LOL, so extensive, You didn't have to throw `structs` in the mix, he has to work on his understanding of pointers and what they mean. (PS) like the array name field :)

Comment: Also as a side note, why not use `IFNDEF` for the then `DEFINE` to effectively leave code out.

Comment: Thanks for the effort and I'll definitely try to do this task once again with structs but as @SGM1 said I have to learn pointers first.

Comment: @SGM1 The first example doesn't use a struct, so OP can use that [the 2nd example was the "extra credit" answer :-)]. But, I've seen many SO questions that have functions that have multiple return values like this. Many answers [not just mine] suggest the struct approach. IMO, if the instructors haven't covered structs yet, then _they_ are messing up by giving a problem like this

Comment: We had a lecture about `structs` but so far it has only been basic stuff. It didn't really occur to me to even try using `structs` for this problem and since I know that pointers are still a taboo for me more or less I thought this is a better idea.

Comment: One of the most effective use of pointers is a pointer to a struct. Or, to loop through arrays using them [which was _not_ done herein]. Go over example 1. It does work. Understand it. After bug fixes, the simplification that comes with eliminating replication by splitting into smaller functions--very important. This helps with catching bugs in one's logic. Note the change in prototype for `Array`. And the notes at the top of the answer. After [all] that, _then_ go for example 2. You'll probably get an understanding of structs that you didn't have before. How they work and _when_ to use them.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark up my code with comments [where missing] as you analyze it. That's what I do when I inherit a code base. Sometimes, it's "// huh?" ;-) A question to help you: In your code, you set the new value _before_ doing `realloc` but in mine, I do it _after_. In my code, does it matter [and if so, why]? _Hint:_ look at code for `B` and `C` in `Array` above the `for` loop in both our `Array` functions. You could also add back your "The idea here is ..." comment into `growarray` with some changes and more line-by-line detail.

Comment: I liked the early emphasis on **ALWAYS READ AND UNDERSTAND COMPILER WARNINGS**. I spotted one early (`for(i = 0 ; i < nA ; i++)`) and thought *"wtf"*? You *almost* got +1 from me for that, but unfortunately after that you misused `realloc`: **`arr = realloc(arr,x);` is *wrong*.** Take note from the question on this topic...

Comment: @Seb Huh? I've double checked the `realloc` and it's fine [AFAICT]. Both examples compile without warnings and run without [apparent] error. Maybe you could explain in more detail what you mean by "wrong"?

Comment: @CraigEstey Nope. I don't need to, because someone else has. Read [this c-faq page](http://c-faq.com/malloc/realloc.html) for an in-detail explanation. While you're there, I recommend reading the rest of the site too.

Comment: @Seb So, no check for null. When I wrote the code, I noticed OP's check [which would still segfault] but then forgot it. For this question, hardly worth it [and not very likely], IMO. My own production code [which I'm more careful with] uses wrappers (e.g. `qrealloc`) that do the check and abort, so I tend to forget about it. When I write device drivers, you'd better believe I check the return of `kmalloc` et. al. And, I've been writing C code for 35+ years, so, regarding the rest of the site, what can I say?

Comment: @CraigEstey No, that's not it. Even if you add null checks, `x = realloc(x, y);` is a broken pattern that results in, in the worst case, memory leaks, and in the best case the program exits immediately, you get useful tools like `valgrind` whinging at you about those "memory leaks". Did you notice how the pattern they recommended later on in that FAQ page was more like: `a = realloc(b, c);`?

Comment: @Seb Thanks, I never realized `realloc` does not always call `free`. I usually just use `malloc`, `calloc`, and `free`.

Comment: @Seb I noticed. But, `a = realloc(a,...); if (a == NULL) abort();` [or equiv] is fine. To shut up `valgrind`, do `b = realloc(a,...); if (b == NULL) abort();`. There is no useful soft recovery for most pgms for out-of-memory once it's occurred [usually due to chain ptr corruption]. If a pgm is _truly_ running out of memory (e.g. wants to alloc 35 GB), it needs to be refactored. For a "robust" pgm, it needs to estimate total memory it will use and not run if it would [later] run out of it. Or, adjust some limits downward beforehand. (i.e.) If a pgm does run out, it's already broken.

Comment: @CraigEstey Seb is totally right here, `realloc` does NOT `free` the pointer it's trying to realloc in case of failure, but would return NULL,  This means it's equivalent to this `int* a = malloc(4); a = malloc(MAX_INT)` the original `malloc(4)` pointer is lost and `malloc(MAX_INT)` probably fails (`a` is now NULL). By that definition alone, you have a memory leak, although albeit, not a significant one.

Comment: @Seb  I don't use valgrind as my pgms are R/T. valgrind has to replace the std alloc fncs to work [unusable]. My pgms get avail memory and adjust alloc sizes/counts to fit. They may take weeks/months for an error to occur. So, my wrappers have builtin leak/overrun detection that runs continuously.

Comment: @SGM1 Reread the thread. If Seb had said initially (e.g.) "What about null check?" that would have been more useful to OP [and myself] rather than the argumentative tone he chose to take where he was shrouding it in mystery. If an OP had said "I get **wrong** results", we'd all say "what do you mean by 'wrong'?", which is what I then asked. He also said the realloc was wrong, but it was the handling of the return value, not the realloc itself [if you just abort on null, which I do--see my 2 new cmts]. There were 19 stmts flagged in OP's code, so I had my hands full fixing them and the logic

Comment: @SGM1 You're right--it is _minor_ [and _unlikely_ here]. Rather than having to plaster null checks around native `malloc` et. al. calls [all over the place], IMO, we ought to teach the use of wrappers that do the check/abort in one place. Most large projects have such wrappers. I've added an example as an update. If we adjust the `realloc` calls to use it, all should be right with the world again ...

Comment: Thanks for all the info and help. I will start reading the link (and the rest of the website) Seb gave and work on pointers. However I also realized that CodeLite isn't helping me that much since I didn't receive any exceptions while compiling. I'm using MinGW and wanted to ask you guys if you can recommend any other IDE? I'm using NetBeans for Java, but I will probably switch to Eclipse.

Comment: For java, use IntelliJ--It's the new hotness. Much better than Eclipse [and this comes from a friend who worked at Sun to provide professional developer support for Java and knows both]. As for C, I don't use an IDE. I have my own build environment that I've developed. For Windows, IIRC, mingw uses gcc which should be able to use `-Wall`. If not, try cygwin. Eclipse might be the choice for C--It _did_ replace some really _horrible_ precursors, but it's been around a while. But, as a _developer_, _when_ you have the time, "man up" and install linux as a dual boot :-)

Comment: I understand that valgrind is not useful for an end user; it's a useful debugging aid. It helps you diagnose memory leaks, such as the one I've been trying to point out. I don't think this is a minor issue at all, because the OP hasn't provided any specific bounds to the size of the array, and `realloc` *will fail* (and memory will be leaked) if this code is used for such large sizes. Unfortunately this means for those who do use valgrind to detect memory leaks during debugging, this means they'll get a false flag that's easy to avoid...

Comment: If it's easy to avoid and it helps debugging, why not take the extra step and write the extra one line of code to avoid it? Oh, and that won't shut valgrind up... You need to remember to `free` the old pointer when `realloc` fails, which is impossible if you overwrite the old pointer with the return value immediately (as in the code you presented in the answer). On the topic of argumentative *tone*, I see no problems having an argument so long as it's civil. Nobody is being offensive; we're just discussing a point, which I hardly think is *minor* since the question is about dynamic allocation.

Comment: Anyway, I was prepare to give +1 following such a *minor* edit but that's not going to happen... I've taken my action and explained it, now I'm happy to move on... Peace :)

Comment: @Seb I'll move on, too [after this]. I added the `qrealloc` as an update. Argumentative _tone_ comes from: (1) saying [the realloc is] "wrong" [in bold] _without_ explanation. To me, that's "tone".  (2) I inferred it was the args and _not_ the missed null check. So, when [I] asked for explanation, you said "Nope. I don't need to ...".  Again, "tone". I send and receive many comments good/bad/indifferent. Yours "stood out". If you had said: (1) "You forgot the null check for realloc" [what I say to other answerers for similar], and (2) [just] "See: link", there would be no "tone"

Comment: `qrealloc` doesn't solve the problem, the link explains the problem, and we don't come here to infer tone; we come here to learn and answer questions. I could apply a sarcastic tone to anything you write, even if you were to say "See: link". Would you be at fault for my misunderstanding as I am for your miscommunication? It doesn't matter, because that's not what we're here for... What I was trying to say is, it's pointless for me to rewrite what someone else has already written. Again, it's not *just* about the null check; it's also about the temporary variable. Anyway, peace & best of luck.